# How to compact and repair an Access database from a Python script

Tags: python-2.7, ms-access, arcgis

I have a python script running from an ArcGIS custom toolbox. The script deals with Access databases (mostly personal geodatabases). What I am wondering is, is there a way to compact and repair an access database (specifically a personal gdb) from my python script?

Thanks in advance for any help and advice,

Ben.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and MS Access 2010.

Answer (score 4):

Use Python's [win32com](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library and make a call to the VBA method [CompactRepair()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193242.aspx). Do note, a backup file path is required (one that does not exist yet) during the process but can be deleted after successful compact, using `os.remove()` for that need:

```
import os
import win32com.client

srcDB = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Database.accdb'
destDB = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Database_backup.accdb'

oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.compactRepair(srcDB, destDB)

os.remove(destDB)
oApp = None
```

Comment: This did not work in my case. The code did not compact & repair the Access DB.

Comment: @shuvonasir, do note this code creates a new database which is the compacted and repaired version of original Access DB.

Comment: It seems like the connection to database through pyodbc isn't getting closed. I've tried to close the connection manually through conn.close(), but still the above code can not run. Giving me permission error because the connection remains open!

Comment: Yes, compacting requires exclusive connection to DB. Close all connections within or outside of Python before compacting. Please ask a different question specific to your case since this solution does not involve `pyodbc`. After asking, let's delete our comments here to not confuse future readers.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. I have created a separate function before connecting the Access DB with pyodbc and compacted & repaired the DB before all other operations done through pyodbc. Your code helped like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just an minor change to the code above to anyone using it in the future (I just had to use this now, thanks Parfait for posting this solution).

The line that states:

```
oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
```

should be

```
oApp = win32com.Dispatch("Access.Application")
```

thanks!

Comment: This line worked for me (Python 3.7, Windows 10):      `oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")`