# How to compact and repair an Access database using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-access, win32com

I'm trying to use Python 3 (specifically 3.7 in my case) to run the 'Compact and Repair Database' function for an Access 2016 database, on Windows 10.

There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202203/how-to-compact-and-repair-an-access-database-from-a-python-script), but this seems to be for Python 2.7 and MS Access 2010. I've tweaked the syntax slightly to:

```
import os
import win32com.client

srcDB = r'C:\My\Database\Path\My_Db.accdb'
destDB = r'C:\My\Database\Path\My_Db_PyBackup.accdb'

oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.compactRepair(srcDB, destDB)
oApp.Application.Quit()
oApp = None

os.remove(destDB)
```

I don't get any errors, and the script runs succesfully. However, the file size remains unchanged - I still have to open the database and manually 'Compact and Repair Database'.

Therefore I'm wondering if there's a different approach that's applicable in newer versions of Python and Access, or whether I've missed something.

Comment: You compact to `destDB` and then delete it. Where is command to replace `srcDB` file with new compacted `destDB`?

Comment: @4dmonster So, the `destDB` is the compacted database? I understood that to be only a backup. In which case, i could instead delete the original, i.e. `srcDB` and rename the `destDB`.

Comment: Someone mentioned in the linked questions that `oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")` should be `oApp = win32com.Dispatch("Access.Application")`

Comment: @Frieder I also noticed that. However i get an `AttributeError: module 'win32com' has no attribute 'Dispatch'` message if i try to use that syntax

Comment: `CompactRepair(SourceFile, DestinationFile, LogFile)` has `SourceFile Required String  - The full path and filename of the database or project file to compact and repair. 
DestinationFile Required String - The full path and filename for where the recovered file will be saved. 
LogFile Optional Boolean - True if a log file is created in the destination directory to record any corruption detected in the source file. A log file is only created if corruption is detected in the source file. If LogFile is False or omitted, no log file is created, even if corruption is detected in the source file.`

Comment: @4dmonster Thanks for the detail regarding the compatRepair() function! All makes a lot more sense now - I've included this in the answer as it makes things a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [4dmonster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1935222/4dmonster)'s more detailed explanation of the `compactRepair()` function, it looks like the above is indeed working as expected:

`CompactRepair(SourceFile, DestinationFile, LogFile)` has `SourceFile Required String - The full path and filename of the database or project file to compact and repair. DestinationFile Required String - The full path and filename for where the recovered file will be saved. LogFile Optional Boolean - True if a log file is created in the destination directory to record any corruption detected in the source file. A log file is only created if corruption is detected in the source file. If LogFile is False or omitted, no log file is created, even if corruption is detected in the source file.`

Therefore, the `destDB` is the compacted database.

With a couple of extra lines I'm able achieve the desired effect. Firstly, use `os.remove()` to delete the original, non-compacted, database `srcDB`. Then use `os.rename()` to rename the new database `destDB` such it has the same name as the original.

The full block of code would therefore look like this:

```
import os
import win32com.client

srcDB = r'C:\My\Database\Path\My_Db.accdb'
destDB = r'C:\My\Database\Path\My_Db_PyBackup.accdb'

oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.compactRepair(srcDB, destDB)
oApp.Application.Quit()
oApp = None

os.remove(srcDB)
os.rename(destDB, srcDB)
```

Thus ending up with a database that has been compacted and repaired which has the same file name as the original.

Comment: We use much more steps. 0. check if there is no users use srcDB 1. compact srcDB to destDB. 2. check if destDB exists 2. rename srcDB to tmpDB 3. check if tmpDB exists 4. delete srcDB 5. check if srcDB **not** exists 6. move destDB to srcDB 7. delete tmpDB.